# Equivalent of gganimate::transition_events on plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

In R, using gganimate, one can make an animated plot where events appear and disappear with time. For example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(gganimate)

df=data.frame(
x=c(1,2,3,4),
y=c(1,2,3,4),
start=c(1,2,3,4),
end=c(5,6,7,8),
en=as_date(1),
ex=as_date(1))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  gganimate::transition_events(
     start=start, 
     end=end, 
     enter_length = as.numeric(en), 
     exit_length = as.numeric(ex))
```

This produces a plot in which points appear according to column "start" and desappear according to column "end".

I wonder if there is an easy way to achieve the same in with plotly (preferably using `ggplotly()`), getting a slider to move along the time.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me, however - you might want to look at [this](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/animations/).

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal, I was missing a pair of lines. I added also calls to library. Took a look to your link but I can't find a way to make a point appear at "start" and disappear at "end"

Comment: After deleting the surplus parenthesis after your data.frame definition this gives me: `Error: enter_length data must be numeric`. You won't find the same approach of `start` and `end` in plotly. Points will disappear when there is no data available in the according animation frame (or the value is NA).

Comment: Sorry again. I double checked and it has to work now. Anyway, thank you for the plotly information. I guess I should transform the data.frame to get 1 line per date and point.

Comment: I just tried to create an example for you and recalled, that I [filed an issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1696) regarding this topic a few month ago. Please support it (thumbs up) to generate some attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `ggplotly`. The result however isn't exactly the same:

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

df = data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  start = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  end = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
  en = as_date(1),
  ex = as_date(1)
)

frame_list <- Map(seq, from = df$start, to = df$end)
DF <- data.frame(x = rep(df$x, times = lengths(frame_list)),
                 y = rep(df$y, times = lengths(frame_list)),
                 frame = unlist(frame_list))

p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = y, frame = frame))

fig <- ggplotly(p)

fig %>%
  animation_opts(
    frame = 0,
    easing = "linear",
    redraw = FALSE,
    mode = "immediate"
  )
fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: I appreciate your answer but still I would have to transform my df into your DF, so I will not mark it as an answer (the input is not the same as in question)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to show. Plotly requires a different input format.

Comment: Yes, so part of the solution is to convert df into DF. You pointed me in the right direction and I appreciate that Thank you!

Comment: Converting your `df` to the required format isn't too hard. Please check my update.

Comment: Thanks, that is great